# If $a,b$ are positive real numbers, such that $a+b=1$, then prove that $(a+ \dfrac {1}{a})^3 +(b+ \dfrac {1}{b})^3 \ge \dfrac {125}{4}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, a.m.-g.m.-inequality, cauchy-schwarz-inequality, holder-inequality

> If $a,b$ are positive real numbers, such that $a+b=1$, then prove that $$\bigg(a+ \dfrac {1}{a}\bigg)^3 +\bigg(b+ \dfrac {1}{b}\bigg)^3 \ge \dfrac {125}{4}$$

I just learnt to prove [If $a$ and $b$ are positive real numbers such that $a+b=1$, then prove that $\big(a+\frac{1}{a}\big)^2 +\big(b+\frac{1}{b}\big)^2 \ge\frac{25}{2}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2439342/if-a-and-b-are-positive-real-numbers-such-that-ab-1-then-prove-that-bi) a few days ago, and it was  just basic application of CS. But I find this one really difficult. I can not apply CS here directly on the numbers $a+\frac{1}{a}$ and $b+\frac{1}{b}$ because CS is for squares. So some manipulation is needed. Anything from hint to full answer will be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By Holder and AM-GM we obtain:
$$\left(a+\frac{1}{a}\right)^3+\left(b+\frac{1}{b}\right)^3=\frac{1}{4}\cdot(1+1)^2\left(\left(a+\frac{1}{a}\right)^3+\left(b+\frac{1}{b}\right)^3\right)\geq$$
$$\geq\frac{1}{4}\left(a+\frac{1}{a}+b+\frac{1}{b}\right)^3=\frac{1}{4}\left(1+\frac{1}{ab}\right)^3\geq\frac{1}{4}\left(1+\frac{1}{\frac{(a+b)^2}{4}}\right)^3=\frac{125}{4}.$$

Also we can use Jensen here.

Indeed, let $f(x)=\left(x+\frac{1}{x}\right)^3$.

Thus, $$f''(x)=\frac{6(x^6+x^2+2)}{x^5}>0$$ for all $x>0$.

Id est, $$\left(a+\frac{1}{a}\right)^3+\left(b+\frac{1}{b}\right)^3\geq2\left(\frac{a+b}{2}+\frac{2}{a+b}\right)^3=\frac{125}{4}.$$

Also we can use AM-GM only.

$$\left(a+\frac{1}{a}\right)^3+\left(b+\frac{1}{b}\right)^3=5+\left(\frac{1}{ab}-1\right)^3-3ab\geq5+(4-1)^3-\frac{3}{4}=\frac{125}{4}.$$

Comment: The first term is squared, not cubed.

Comment: Let me learn this Holder first from  wikipedia!

Comment: @marty cohen It's a typo in the given.

Comment: i think Michael, you have misreaded the given problem

Comment: ok it was corrected right now

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner No no! Extremely sorry! It's cube, I made a typo

Comment: @a m i t y a s I think in the Wikipedia Holder written in the sadistic-masochistic style. I think it would be better if you'll see here: https://math.stackexchange.com/tags/holder-inequality/info Good luck!

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg Your process must be correct, but I am looking for an answer that uses AM-GM, CS and a few other easy inequalities. I got this question in CS chapter of a book

Comment: @a m i t y a s I have found a proof by AM-GM only. See now.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg How is $\frac{1}{4}\left(a+\frac{1}{a}+b+\frac{1}{b}\right)^3=\frac{1}{4}\left(1+\frac{1}{ab}\right)^3$? The RHS should have a factor $(a+b)^3$

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg Oh no! Sorry, I forgot that $a+b=1$

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg Thank you very much. I have learnt the Holder thing!

Answer (score 2):

An alternative approach: $h(x)=x+\frac{1}{x}$ is positive and log-convex over $(0,1)$, since 
$$\frac{d^2}{dx^2}\log h(x)=\frac{(1+3x^2)+(x^2-x^4)}{(x+x^3)^2}>0.$$
In particular $h(x)^3$ is convex and the claim follows from Jensen inequality, as already remarked by Micheal Rozenberg.

Answer (score 1):

Let $a=\cos^2 t,b=\sin^2 t$. 
Note
$$ \cos^6t+\sin^6t=(\cos^2t+\sin^2t)(\cos^4t-\cos^2t\sin^2t+\sin^4t)=1-3\cos^2t\sin^2t. $$
Then
\begin{eqnarray}
&&(a+\frac1a)^3+(b+\frac1b)^3\\
&=&(\cos^2t+\sec^2t)^3+(\sin^2t+\csc^2t)^3\\
&=&\cos^6t+3\cos^4t\sec^2t+3\cos^2t\sec^4t\\
&&+\sin^6t+3\sin^4t\csc^2t+3\sin^2t\csc^4t+\csc^6t\\
&=&(\cos^6t+\sin^6t)+3(\cos^2t+\sin^2t)+3(\sec^2t+\csc^2t)+\frac{\cos^6t+\sin^6t}{\cos^6t\sin^6t}\\
&=&4-3\cos^2t\sin^2t+\frac{3}{\sin^2t\cos^2t}+\frac{1-3\cos^2t\sin^2t}{\cos^6t\sin^6t}
\end{eqnarray}
Let $x=\cos^2t\sin^2t$ and then $x\in(0,\frac14]$. Define
$$ f(x)=4-3x+\frac3x+\frac{1-3x}{x^3}. $$
Then
$$ f'(x)=-3-\frac3{x^2}+\frac{8x-3}{x^4}<0, x\in(0,\frac12]$$
and hence
$$ f(x)\ge f(\frac12)=\frac{125}{4}. $$
So
$$ (a+\frac1a)^3+(b+\frac1b)^3\ge\frac{125}{4}$$