# Solving an equality in 2 variables

Tags: inequality

I need to prove that

$$\left(a + \frac{1}{a}\right)^2 +\left(b + \frac{1}{b}\right)^2 \gt \frac{25}{2}$$

if $a+b = 1$  and $a b \le 1/4$

I'd like a hint. Solve the equality first to $a$ or $b$, or stay in a and b as to get
$a b \le 4$ in the inequality ?

Comment: Wouldn't it be a pro to have a preview of your answer you can check your Latex formulas ?

Comment: @Ignace the preview of the answer *does* show latex-versions of the text, you just have to use it (dollar signs and all)

Comment: Saw the inequality link. Thanks. Just what is your hint ?

Comment: A preview would prevent you from going in and out with the edit function to correct errors, so that If it looks pretty good you submit. Sure The answer gives the latex if it's there.

Comment: $\;a=3\,,\,b=-2\;$ is another counterexample...out of many more.

Comment: @Ignace for feature proposals, try meta.math.stackexchange.com.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/487486/proving-inequality-a-frac1a2-b-frac1b2-geq-frac252-for

Answer (score 2):

Apply Cauchy-Schwarz Inequality to argue that,

$(a+\frac{1}{a}+b+\frac{1}{b})^2 \le (1+1)((a+\frac{1}{a})^2+(b+\frac{1}{b})^2)$,

And further, $\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b} = \frac{a+b}{ab}=\frac{1}{ab}\ge \frac{4}{(a+b)^2}=4$.

So the first expression becomes,

$25=(1+4)^2 \le (a+\frac{1}{a}+b+\frac{1}{b})^2 \le (1+1)((a+\frac{1}{a})^2+(b+\frac{1}{b})^2)$

That is $(a+\frac{1}{a})^2+(b+\frac{1}{b})^2 \ge 25/2$.

and Equality holds iff $a=b=\frac12$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

Put $\;b=1-a\;$ in the left side of the inequality to prove, so:

$$\left(a+\frac1a\right)^2+\left(1-a+\frac1{1-a}\right)^2=a^2+2+\frac1{a^2}+(1-a)^2+2+\frac1{(1-a)^2}=$$

$$=2a^2-2a+5+\frac{2a^2-2a+1}{\left(a(1-a)\right)^2}$$

But it is given that

$$\frac14>ab=a(1-a)=a-a^2\iff a(a-1)=a^2-a>-\frac14\;\ldots$$

Try to take it from here now...and check the inequality sign.

Comment: isn't it < in stead of > at the last 1/4...

Comment: No, but in fact it should be $$ab=a(1-a)\le\frac14\implies a(a-1)\ge-\frac14\ldots$$

Comment: given the equation to be solved that gives: x > 1/2 + 5 x meaning 2 times a^2 -a. so 5 + x.  x > 1/2 + 1 as nominator. We have to multiply the denominator by -1.

Comment: @Ignace I can't understand your mathematics writing. Please do use LaTeX

Answer (score 1):

$$
\begin{align}
\hspace{-1cm}\left(a+\frac1a\right)^2+\left(b+\frac1b\right)^2
&\ge2\left(a+\frac1a\right)\left(b+\frac1b\right)\tag{1}\\
&=\frac2{ab}\left(a^2+1\right)\left(b^2+1\right)\\
&\ge8\left(a^2+1\right)\left(b^2+1\right)\tag{2}\\
&=8\small\left(\left(a-\tfrac12\right)^2+\left(a-\tfrac12\right)+\tfrac54\right)\left(\left(a-\tfrac12\right)^2-\left(a-\tfrac12\right)+\tfrac54\right)\\
&=8\left[\left(\left(a-\tfrac12\right)^2+\tfrac54\right)^2-\left(a-\tfrac12\right)^2\right]\\
&=8\left[\left(a-\tfrac12\right)^4+\tfrac32\left(a-\tfrac12\right)^2+\tfrac{25}{16}\right]\\[4pt]
&\ge\frac{25}{2}\tag{3}
\end{align}
$$
Inequalities:
$(1)$: $(x-y)^2\ge0\implies x^2+y^2\ge2xy$
$(2)$: $ab\le\tfrac14$
$(3)$: $x^2\ge0$