# If $a,b>0$ and $a+b=1\;,$ Then minumum value of $(a+\frac{1}{a})^2+(b+\frac{1}{b})^2$ is

Tags: inequality

If $a,b>0$ and $a+b=1\;,$ Then minumum value of $\displaystyle \left(a+\frac{1}{a}\right)^2+\left(b+\frac{1}{b}\right)^2$ is

$\bf{My\; Try::}$ Let $a=\sin^2 \theta$ and $b=\cos^2 \theta\;,$ Then We have to minimize

$$\displaystyle f(\theta) = (\sin^2 \theta+\csc^2 \theta)^2+(\cos^2 \theta+\sec ^2 \theta) = \sin^4 \theta+\csc^4 \theta+\cos^4 \theta+\sec^4 \theta+4$$

So $$f(\theta) = 1-2\sin^2 \theta\cos^2 \theta+\frac{1}{\sin^2 \theta \cos^2 \theta}+4$$

So $$f(\theta) = 1-\frac{\sin^2 2\theta}{2}+\frac{4}{\sin^2 \theta}+4$$

Now Put $\sin^2 2\theta = t\;, t\in \left(0,1\right]$

So we get $$f(t)=5-\frac{t}{2}+\frac{4}{t}\;,$$ So we get $\displaystyle f'(t) = -\frac{1}{2}-\frac{4}{t^2}<0\;\forall t \in (0,1]$

So $$f(1)_{\min} = 5-\frac{1}{2}+4=9-\frac{1}{2}=\frac{17}{2}$$

But answer given as $$\frac{25}{2}$$

plz help me, Where I am wrong, Thanks

Comment: A simpler solution: $f(x) = \left(x + \frac{1}{x}\right)^2$ satisfy $f''(x) = 2 + \frac{6}{x^4} > 0$ so $f$ is [convex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_function#Properties) on $[0,1]$ and therefore
$$f(a) + f(b) \geq 2f\left(\frac{a+b}{2}\right) = 2f\left(\frac{1}{2}\right) = \frac{25}{2}$$

Comment: @Winther I think your post could be posted as an answer. (A very elegant answer, if I may say so.)

Comment: Now I found that there is another question about the same inequality: [Proving inequality $(a+\frac{1}{a})^2 + (b+\frac{1}{b})^2 \geq \frac{25}{2}$ for $a+b=1$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/487486/proving-inequality-a-frac1a2-b-frac1b2-geq-frac252-for)

Comment: juantheron: If the main point of your question is to discuss this particular attempt to prove the inequality, you should probably add the ([tag:proof-verification]) tag. If you are interested in any proof, then it is duplicate of the older question. (And even if it is proof verification question, if you are already satisfied with the comments you have received on your proof, I think that it can be closed as a duplicate. So that if other users are looking for this inequality and find this question, they are directed to the older one.)

Comment: Excellent solution by Winther. but can i know how to prove equality occurs when $a=b=0.5$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Where I am wrong

In the following part :

> $$f(\theta) = 1-2\sin^2 \theta\cos^2 \theta+\frac{1}{\sin^2 \theta \cos^2 \theta}+4$$

This is not correct.

$$\begin{align}f(\theta)&=\sin^4\theta+\cos^4\theta+\frac{1}{\sin^4\theta}+\frac{1}{\cos^4\theta}+4\\&=(\sin^2\theta+\cos^2\theta)^2-2\sin^2\theta\cos^2\theta+\frac{(\sin^2\theta+\cos^2\theta)^2-2\sin^2\theta\cos^2\theta}{\sin^4\theta\cos^4\theta}+4\\&=1-2\sin^2\theta\cos^2\theta+\frac{1-2\sin^2\theta\cos^2\theta}{\sin^4\theta\cos^4\theta}+4\end{align}$$

---

As you did, you can put $\sin^22\theta=t$ to see that $$f(t)=\frac{16}{t^2}-\frac t2-\frac 8t+5$$
is decreasing for $0\lt t\le 1$, so the answer is $f(1)=\frac{25}{2}$ as desired.

Answer (score 4):

The following is not true
$$\sin^4 \theta+\csc^4 \theta+\cos^4 \theta+\sec^4 \theta+4=1-2\sin^2 \theta\cos^2 \theta+\frac{1}{\sin^2 \theta \cos^2 \theta}+4.$$

For example, let $\theta=\pi/4$. Then $\text{LHS}=1/4+4+1/4+4+4=12.5$, while $\text{RHS}=1-1/2+4+4=8.5$.

Answer (score 3):

Here is an alternative solution: take $f(x) = \left(x + \frac{1}{x}\right)^2$ then $f''(x) = 2 + \frac{6}{x^4} > 0$ so $f$ is a [convex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_function#Properties) function and therefore satisfy 
$$f(a) + f(b) \geq 2f\left(\frac{a+b}{2}\right) = 2f\left(\frac{1}{2}\right) = \frac{25}{2}$$

This argument can also be used to solve other similar types of problems. For example we have the following generalization: if $f:[0,1]\to\mathbb{R}$ is a convex function and $x_i\in[0,1]$ with $x_1+\ldots+x_n = 1$ then $\min\sum_{i=1}^nf(x_i) = nf\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)$.

Comment: Can we use Jensen's inequality to prove equality condition that is Minimum occurs when $a=b=0.5$

Comment: @Umeshshankar The inequality I use here *is* Jensens.

Comment: Yes i am asking Jensen's inequality is an equality when the curve is a straight line. But here the curve is not a line?

Comment: @Umeshshankar Jensen's inequality, $tf(a) + (1-t)f(b) \geq f(ta + (1-t)b)$, is an equality *for all* $t\in[0,1]$ only when the curve is a straight line. It can be an equality for a single value without it being a straight line.

Comment: ok do you mean to say $f(x)$ is a constant function

Comment: What are you talking about? I don't understand where you got that from and what you are trying to understand

Comment: Because if $f(x)=c$ is a constant function we have $f(a)=c=f(b)=f(ta+(1-t)b)$ Then we get $tc+(1-t)c \ge c$ which is actually an equality.So $\left(a+\frac{1}{a}\right)^2=\left(b+\frac{1}{b}\right)^2=c=\frac{25}{4}$ from which we get $a=b=0.5$ Am i right?

Comment: The function in question is not the constant function so that argument makes little sense

Comment: It can be an equality for a single value without it being a straight line. Can you explain this please