# Let $p$ and $q$ be positive numbers having a sum of $1.$ What is the minimum value of $(p+(1/p))^2 + (q+(1/q))^2?$

Tags: polynomials, quadratics

Options are: 
A. $20$
B. $12$
C. $12.5$
D. $13.3$

And steps to  calculate would be appreciated.

Edit: Apologies for having repeated the same question here.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/487486/proving-inequality-a-frac1a2-b-frac1b2-geq-frac252-for